# How to set HubSection Header Style

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I want to change Font Family, Font Size and Foreground color for HubSection Header.

Something like this:

```
<Style TargetType="HubSection" x:Key="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="Header">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="100"></Setter> 
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </Setter.Value>            
    </Setter>        
</Style>


<HubSection Width="500" Header="Section Name" Style="{StaticResource HubSection}">
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property you want to change isn't `Header` but `HeaderTemplate`. Here's my working example:

```
<Style TargetType="HubSection">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                           FontSize="100"
                           Foreground="Yellow"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you want to apply this style to all `Hub` controls in your app, just remove the `Key` and place it in the **App.xaml** file in `Resources`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to override header template you can override default theme resources:

```
    <FontWeight x:Key="HubSectionHeaderThemeFontWeight">SemiLight</FontWeight>
    <x:Double x:Key="HubSectionHeaderThemeFontSize">26.667</x:Double>
```

Unfortunately there is no special resources for FontFamily and Foreground. Template is using defaults from Button. So you will influence whole application. But in many cases that's what you want, right?

```
 <FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
```